# Updating Tomtom GPS map (without a virtual box / wine solution)

Tags: updates, gps

I have a Tomtom Via 130 GPS and would like to update my map.

On their website they ask to install a software, but Ubuntu is not supported (neither other linux distributions). Quite amazing for a device developed on a linux kernel.

Is there a way to do it without a virtual box ?

I don't consider the virtual box option because my system is very light. And this is another question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a little research, I can give a response :

Unless you have different infos, and i hope you will, response is NO.

[pyTomtom](http://code.google.com/p/pytomtom/) (developed in python) and [jTomtom](http://jtomtom.sourceforge.net/accueil/) (developed in Java) are 2 projects that are able to updates several model of GPS.

Unfortunately, they don't support Via 130 (and most of the recent models).

This because the device is not recognized as an external drive or storage device, but as a network interface card. Funny confirmation of this : when you plug in your GPS and switch it on, you will have the standard Network Connection message (Network enabled / Network disabled).

So it seems that the solution of updating a Via130 Tomtom Model goes through virtualization (with an emulator that support USB) or wine.